# Trying to sort an array in ascending order, using a function that finds smallest value in the array?

Tags: c++

I have an assignment that I have been stuck on, and unable to figure out after quite a bit of research.

I need to sort an array of size 20 with values between 1 and 101, using a function that returns the smallest value in the array.

Here is my function that returns the smallest value in the array.

```
int problem5(int *arr, int size, int &m, int &n){//Definition Problem 5
    int smallest = 101; 
    int smallestindex;
    for ( int i=0;  i < size;  ++i ){
        if ( arr[i] < smallest ){
            smallest = arr[i];
            smallestindex = i;
        }
    }
    m=smallest;
    n=smallestindex;
    cout<<"Smallest value is "<<m<<endl;
    cout<<"It's index is "<<n<<endl;
    return n; 
}`
```

And here is my function, I am trying to switch the index of the first value in the array with the index of the smallest value, then have the array not include the first value(smallest value) in the new array. Here is that code:

```
void problem8(int *x, int size){
    int m = 101;
    int n = 101;
    int tmpsize = size;
    problem4(x,20);
    for(int i =0; i<size; i++){
        swap(x[i],x[problem5(&x[i],tmpsize, m, n)]);
        tmpsize = tmpsize - 1;
    }      
}`
```

For the first few loops it will not change the array, but will correctly identify the smallest value. Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: You should try using [your debugger](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Easy.  Use `std::sort` to sort the array, then the value in the first slot will be the smallest.

Comment: What is the definition for `problem4()`?

Comment: I highly recommend naming functions for what they do, not what problem number they solve (or were used for).

Comment: problem4() just prints out the array on one line, sorry I should have included that. Unfortunately due to our instructions we must name them by the problem number, but I should have changed when I posted for more readability. std::sort is not working either unfortunately, and I would also like to sort it using the problem5(findSmallest()) function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
swap(x[i], x[problem5(&x[i], tmpsize, m, n)]);
```

should be

```
problem5(&x[i], tmpsize, m, n);
swap(x[i], x[n]);
```

as currently you probably have out of bound access.

I suggest also to rename your variable `n`, `m` in `problem8` into something like `smallIndex`, `smallestValue`. to result to something like:

```
int find_min(const int* arr, int size, int& value, int& index)
{
    int smallest = 101; 
    int smallestindex;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        if (arr[i] < smallest) {
            smallest = arr[i];
            smallestindex = i;
        }
    }
    value = smallest;
    index = smallestindex;
    return n; 
}

int problem5(int* arr, int size, int& m, int& n)
{
    int res = find_min(arr, size, m, n)
    std::cout << "Smallest value is "<< m << std::endl;
    std::cout << "It's index is " << n << std::endl;
    return res;
}

void selection_sort(int* x, int size)
{
    int value = 101;
    int index = 101;
    int tmpsize = size;

    for(int i = 0; i<size; i++) {
        problem5(&x[i], tmpsize, value, index);
        swap(x[i], x[index]);
        tmpsize = tmpsize - 1;
    }
}

void problem8(int* x, int size){
    problem4(x, 20); // better name ?
    selection_sort(x, size);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input on the names. Unfortunately due to my professor's directions, we must use problemX() for the function name, but I did change the actual variables. I read your changes and it kind of clicked, and I assumed it would work perfectly, but it is still returning the same results. Thank you for the help though, I appreciate the pointers.

Comment: I kept `problemX` name, as I suppoesed that it was required, but you can create sub functions with good names.